# Water Supply for Toliet, changing shut off valve to Sharkbite

Tags: plumbing

I have the following shut off value for the toliet.
[image]

[image]

I want to change this to a Sharkbite fitting. It's not leaking, but I am  redoing the bathroom, so I might as well change everything. I changed the faucet lines to sharkbite just fine because they were copper. However, this pipe is not copper, and quite honestly, i do not know what it is. It does look like its some sort of sleeve over a copper line...see picture below.

[image]

It looks like a decorative supply kit...something found here:https://www.signaturehardware.com/toilet-supply-kit-with-1-2-od-x-3-8-od-angle-stop.html --> but I am not 100% sure.

Can this be cut and have a 1/2in Sharkbite fitting places on it? And if it can, would this cut it just fine?

[image]
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-5-8-in-Junior-Tube-Cutter-80-511-111/304384093

Its the only one I have.

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: the chrome plated pipe is larger than the copper pipe ... Sharkbite would probably not fit ... why don't you cut the copper pipe?

Comment: @jsotola, i could, but then I assume I would have to make that pipe longer because it looks like that chrome pipe leaves me about 1 inch of copper at the base

Comment: It's odd for a valve to stick out that far anyway. An inch might be enough. You can always unsweat (desweat?) the sleeve.

Comment: thank you for the tour, @isherwood. Im on stack overflow often, so im well verse how it works here.... ANYWAY, i guess u have a point if worst comes to worse. I prefer not to have a nub sticking out of the wall though. :) lol

Comment: I would think twice about doing this. There is literally no advantage to this whatsoever, and sharkbite fittings don't last as long as sweated copper.  The pipe sticks out that far because that's where the toilet inlet was, and these used to be plumbed with straight copper line, so this minimizes curves.

Comment: _What_ in _the_ world is that plugging up the outlet of the valve?? How long did it take for the toilet tank to refill?

Comment: @FreeMan it was dust. i was working in the bathroom laying floor, etc.